# Error (#100) Invalid message data - Open Graph Facebook

Tags: php, laravel, message, facebook-opengraph, attachment

I'm trying to send an image using the OpenGraph API from my application to an Instagram account (note that I can send and receive text). I'm using:

- the Laravel library "joelbutcher/facebook-graph-sdk": "6.0.0"
- the endpoint "/me/messages"

The issue is that the message is being sent (I receive the image), but I'm encountering the following error:
"(#100) Invalid message data" with subcode error 2534015.

The structure I'm using to send the attachment is as follows:

```
$params = array();
$params['recipient']['id'] = $recipient_id;
$params['messaging_type'] = 'RESPONSE';
$params['message']['attachment']['type'] = 'image';
$params['message']['attachment']['payload']['url'] = $attachment['url'];
$params['message']['attachment']['payload']['is_reusable'] = true;
$params['platform'] = "instagram";
```

I tried sending the attachment using the tool provided by Meta to test the APIs (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) using the same data structure, and it doesn't give me any errors.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some debugging I was able to fix it by transforming

```
$params['message']['attachment']['payload']['is_reusable'] = true;
```

to

```
$params['message']['attachment']['payload']['is_reusable'] = "true";
```

By not putting true in quotes, the system automatically translates it into 1 and Facebook recognizes it as invalid data.